# torch.Tensor vs. torch.FloatTensor in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor

What is the relationship between `torch.Tensor` and `torch.FloatTensor`? In the Pytorch document, its says that `torch.Tensor` is an alias for `torch.FloatTensor`. I don’t quiet understand what this means.

For example, I created a tensor `x` using `torch.tensor` function which should return an instance of `torch.Tensor` class.

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([1., 2.])
>>> isinstance(x, torch.Tensor)
True
>>> isinstance(x, torch.FloatTensor)
True
>>> issubclass(torch.FloatTensor, torch.Tensor)
False
```

It turns out `x` is an instance of `torch.FloatTensor` as well as `torch.Tensor`. So, I initially thought that `torch.FloatTensor` was a subclass of `torch.Tensor`, which it turned out that it wasn’t!!

How is this possible that `x` is an instance of both `torch.FloatTensor` and `torch.Tensor` when these two classes are not in inheritence relationship?

Also, what is the relationship between `torch.Tensor` and `torch.FloatTensor` and how are they different?